# How to put advertising on phonegap offline mobile app?

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, ads

I just made an Android app, and i was wondering if is possible to add an offline advertisting using phonegap.
it is possible that? 
if yes, how?

Comment: Advertising with ad mob, or what? Please post more details to get a more detailed answer.

Comment: mm admob, because i've tried adsense but offline it doesn't work